# Lsode throwing INTDY-- T (=R1) ILLEGAL and invalid input detected

Tags: matlab, math, octave, differential-equations

I have my function:

```
function [result] = my_func(x,y)
  result = y^2*(1-3*x)-3*y;
endfunction
```

Also, my vector with Ts, my function address and my initial variable x_0

```
load file_with_ts
# Add my limits as I also want to calculate those 
# (all values in file_with_ts are within those limits.)
t_points = [-1, file_with_ts, 2]
myfunc = str2func("my_func")
x_0 = 0.9142
```

I am trying to execute the following line:

```
lsode_d1 = lsode(myfunc, x_0, t_points)
```

And expecting a result, but getting the following error:

```
 INTDY--  T (=R1) ILLEGAL
      In above message,  R1 =  0.7987082301475D+00
       T NOT IN INTERVAL TCUR - HU (= R1) TO TCUR (=R2)
      In above,  R1 =  0.8091168896311D+00   R2 =  0.8280400838323D+00
 LSODE--  TROUBLE FROM INTDY. ITASK = I1, TOUT = R1
      In above message,  I1 =         1
      In above message,  R1 =  0.7987082301475D+00
error: lsode: invalid input detected (see printed message)
error: called from
    main at line 20 column 10
```

Also, the variable sizes are:

x_0 -> 1x1

t_points -> 1x153

myfunc -> 1x1

I tried transposing the t_points vector

using @my_func instead of the str2func function

I tried adding multiple variables as the starting point (instead of x_0 I entered [x_0; x_1])

Tried changing my function header from my_func(x, y) to my_func(y, x)

Read the documentation and confirmed that my_func allows x to be a vector and returns a vector (whenever x is a vector).

EDIT: T points is the following 1x153 matrix (with -1 and 2 added to the beggining and the end respectively):

-4.9451e-01
-4.9139e-01
-4.7649e-01
-4.8026e-01
-4.6177e-01
-4.5412e-01
-4.4789e-01
-4.2746e-01
-4.1859e-01
-4.0983e-01
-4.0667e-01
-3.8436e-01
-3.7825e-01
-3.7150e-01
-3.5989e-01
-3.5131e-01
-3.4875e-01
-3.3143e-01
-3.2416e-01
-3.1490e-01
-3.0578e-01
-2.9267e-01
-2.9001e-01
-2.6518e-01
-2.5740e-01
-2.5010e-01
-2.4017e-01
-2.3399e-01
-2.1491e-01
-2.1067e-01
-2.0357e-01
-1.8324e-01
-1.8112e-01
-1.7295e-01
-1.6147e-01
-1.5424e-01
-1.4560e-01
-1.1737e-01
-1.1172e-01
-1.0846e-01
-1.0629e-01
-9.4327e-02
-8.0883e-02
-6.6043e-02
-6.6660e-02
-6.1649e-02
-4.7245e-02
-2.8332e-02
-1.8043e-02
-7.7416e-03
-6.5142e-04
1.0918e-02
1.7619e-02
3.4310e-02
3.3192e-02
5.2275e-02
5.5756e-02
6.8326e-02
8.2764e-02
9.5195e-02
9.4412e-02
1.1630e-01
1.2330e-01
1.2966e-01
1.3902e-01
1.4891e-01
1.5848e-01
1.7012e-01
1.8026e-01
1.9413e-01
2.0763e-01
2.1233e-01
2.1895e-01
2.3313e-01
2.4092e-01
2.4485e-01
2.6475e-01
2.7154e-01
2.8068e-01
2.9258e-01
3.0131e-01
3.0529e-01
3.1919e-01
3.2927e-01
3.3734e-01
3.5841e-01
3.5562e-01
3.6758e-01
3.7644e-01
3.8413e-01
3.9904e-01
4.0863e-01
4.2765e-01
4.2875e-01
4.3468e-01
4.5802e-01
4.6617e-01
4.6885e-01
4.7247e-01
4.8778e-01
4.9922e-01
5.1138e-01
5.1869e-01
5.3222e-01
5.4196e-01
5.4375e-01
5.5526e-01
5.6629e-01
5.7746e-01
5.8840e-01
6.0006e-01
5.9485e-01
6.1771e-01
6.3621e-01
6.3467e-01
6.5467e-01
6.6175e-01
6.6985e-01
6.8091e-01
6.8217e-01
6.9958e-01
7.1802e-01
7.2049e-01
7.3021e-01
7.3633e-01
7.4985e-01
7.6116e-01
7.7213e-01
7.7814e-01
7.8882e-01
8.1012e-01
7.9871e-01
8.3115e-01
8.3169e-01
8.4500e-01
8.4168e-01
8.5705e-01
8.6861e-01
8.8211e-01
8.8165e-01
9.0236e-01
9.0394e-01
9.2033e-01
9.3326e-01
9.4164e-01
9.5541e-01
9.6503e-01
9.6675e-01
9.8129e-01
9.8528e-01
9.9339e-01

Comment: Please post a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) that anybody can run to help finding the problem. Here in particular we don't know what's in `t_points`

Comment: Is the time array strictly monotonous? In the current step from 0.8091 to 0.8280 the interpolator is asked to produce a value at 0.7987, which should not happen if the output times are monotonous.

Comment: @LutzLehmann indeed I was just testing with a monotonous `t_points` array, and it works well. Inserting a non-monotonous point in array results in the same error as in the question.

Comment: The time loop is constructed to forget the history to use minimal memory. So if going back for the output values means to access the previous internal method step, that data just is not there. Thus in most cases non-monotonous time arrays will give that error.

Comment: @PierU I added the t_points to my example, seems like not being monotonous causes this issue. However, I am explicitly asked to implement a different solution and compare to the lsode function and I'm so far the only one having this problem (everyone has the same values)

Comment: Maybe the other ones have already fixed the errors. You need to sort the array in increasing order before using it, and of course report that you had to do so.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Credits to Lutz Lehmann and PierU.

The problem lied in the array t_points not being a monotonous array. Adding a  sort(t_points) before doing any calculations fixed the error.